# Dataweave scripting error - the reference to the function Batch::getStepExceptions() cannot be resolved

Tags: mule, batch-processing

I have a Mule flow that has the batch processor.  The last batch step is intended to catch failed records and send them to an ActiveMQ queue.  The first processor in the step is a Set-Payload with the following code:

```
<batch:step
                    name="FailedCustomerUpsertHandlingBatchStep"
                    doc:id="2bcfc78a-57b9-4be5-a2fd-3c15da720f95"
                    acceptPolicy="ONLY_FAILURES">
                    <set-payload
                        value="#[Batch::getStepExceptions()]"
                        doc:name="Set Payload"
                        doc:id="a71dd374-4623-4989-b938-53f1825e7d9d" />
```

In the Problems pane of Anypoint Studio, there is an error listed as follows:

```
Scripting language error on expression 'Batch::getStepExceptions()'. Reason: Unable to resolve reference of Batch::getStepExceptions..  salesforce-to-mysql-sync-with-batch.xml /salesforce-to-MySQL-DB-using-Batch-Processing/src/main/mule    Set Payload Message Flow Error
```

I found an example of this in the Mulesoft docs [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/batch-error-handling-faq)

The app is on Mule runtime 4.2.1 and the scripting module 1.1.2 is installed.

Why can't anypoint recognize the DW Function?`Batch::getStepExceptions()`

Answer (score 2):

This will/should still work at runtime. At the moment, it doesn't resolve in Studio. You can ignore the error.

Answer (score 0):

IN my case still failing at runtime :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

got it to work :

[image]

Had to click the fx